# how to zend zf create partial

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-view

I'm creating a partial manually by creating a partials folder in `layouts/scripts/partials` and then creating the `mypartial.phtml`. Is there a command to do this quicker, like maybe?

`zf create partial`

I don't think this exists but is there something similar or anything quicker than this manual way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zf create view` is about as close as you get at the moment. `zf --help` will give you all the commands.

As much as I like code generation tools as time savers, what benefit would you really get here if such a command existed? Creating a partial is as simple as creating a blank file on the file system - Zend Tool can't guess any of the contents. You can always do `touch layouts/scripts/partials/something.phtml` if you happen to have the terminal window open already.